# Is there a good way to search by both key and value?

Tags: c++, stl

I am currently using `map<int, int>` in C++. I can check for the existence of a key without a problem but is there an efficient way to retrieve the keys that a particular value has as well? My purpose is to grab all the elements with a given value and then update their value.

Comment: There's a fairly good chance that there's a better data structure for your problem. Could you describe what you're doing in general?

Comment: Actually, I am playing around with this question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3848239/trying-to-group-values I came up with a solution and am seeing if I can implement it in C++. I haven't verified my own version of the solution yet but I was wondering how this problem is actually solved if efficiency is a concern.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You might be interested in [Boost.Bimap](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_44_0/libs/bimap/doc/html/index.html).

Comment: Thanks. Will look into it now and get back.

Comment: this is definitely very useful +1

Answer (score 0):

Now it is easy with c++11 and above.

Try below sample.

```
//DECLARE A MAP
std::map<int, int> testmap;

//SAMPLE DATA
testmap.insert(std::make_pair(1, 10));
testmap.insert(std::make_pair(2, 20));
testmap.insert(std::make_pair(3, 30));
testmap.insert(std::make_pair(4, 20));

//ELEMENTS WITH VALUE TO BE FOUND
int value = 20;

//RESULTS
std::map<int,int> keysMatching;

//ONE STEP TO FIND ALL MATCHING MAP ELEMENTS
std::copy_if(testmap.begin(), testmap.end(), std::inserter(keysMatching, keysMatching.end()), [value](const auto& v) {return v.second == value; });
```